# An example of a bounded pseudo Cauchy sequence that diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Harmonic series diverges and pseudo Cauchy however it's not bounded. So how can I find such a sequence?

A sequence $(s_n)$ is pseudo-Cauchy if, for all $\xi>0$, there exists an $N$ such that if $n ≥ N$, then $|s_{n+1}−s_n| < ξ$.

Comment: What is a pseudo-Cauchy sequence?

Comment: $$\textstyle 0,\,{1\over 2},\, 1,\,  {2\over 3},\,{1\over 3},\,{0},\,{1\over 4},\,{2\over 4},\,{3\over 4},\,1,\,{4\over 5},\,{3\over 5},\,{2\over 5},\,{1\over 5},  \,0, \ldots$$

Comment: A sequence (sn) is pseudo-Cauchy if, for all  ξ> 0, there exists an N such that if n ≥ N, then |sn+1−sn| < ξ

Comment: @DavidMitra How would you go about proving the sequence using the definition? I'm struggling to understand how to begin that part.

Answer (score 5):

Try the sequence $$a_n=\sin\sqrt n$$

Comment: It's bounded and divergent, however it's not pseudo Cauchy.

Comment: @user11111 $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Nicer than my example.

Comment: @user11111 My last comment implies Hagen's sequence is indeed pseudo-Cauchy.

Comment: Be careful here, we want to show  |sn+1−sn| < ξ but not n+1 - n .So Sin(n) can be any number when n goes to infinite, thus it's not pseudo Cauchy.

Comment: @user11111 By the Mean Value Theorem, $|\sin\sqrt{n+1}-\sin\sqrt n|\le|\sqrt{n+1}- \sqrt n|{\rightarrow} 0$.

Comment: Mean value Theorem is applied to a continuous function, can we use it in a discontinuous Sequence?

Comment: I'm still not sure about this one. We are talking about the sequence sin(1), sin(2), sin(3)..... but not the sin function.