# Pseudo-Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I have never seen this terminology before, so I will provide the given definition.

A Pseudo-Cauchy sequence is : A sequence $(a_n)$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{n+1} - a_n | \leq \epsilon \space \forall \space n \geq  N$

So then my question is that is a pseudo-cauchy sequence always converging?

Comment: This seems to be almost duplicate of [Is a bounded sequence such that $\lim(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$ necessarily Cauchy?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768404/boundedness-and-cauchy-sequence-is-a-bounded-sequence-such-that-lima-n1-a) and [An example of a bounded pseudo Cauchy sequence that diverges?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528753/an-example-of-a-bounded-pseudo-cauchy-sequence-that-diverges). (The only difference is that you do not require boundedness.)

Comment: Here is a related question: [Why doesn't $d(x_n,x_{n+1})\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ imply ${x_n}$ is Cauchy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/107336)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n {1\over k}.$$

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but since $\frac{1}{k} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, does this sequence not converge?

I know the harmonic series is divergent, but the question is in particular asking for a pseudo-cauchy sequence which does not converge.

Comment: @elbarto The sequence $a_n$ is Pseudo-Cauchy because $|a_{n+1} - a_n| = \frac{1 }{n+1}$.  The key is that you're only comparing every $n\geq N$ to $n+1$, rather than an arbitrary $m$ as is in the Cauchy Sequence definition.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. I agree it is Cauchy, but it doesn't diverge. The sequence $(a_n)  = \frac{1}{n} \to 0 \space \text{as} \space n \to \infty$

However, I quickly realized mathsadist was referring to the sequence of the partial sums can be used as an example, which is fine :)

Answer (score 8):

Consider the sequence
$$0,1,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},1,\frac{3}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5},1,\frac{5}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{3}{6},\frac{2}{6},\frac{1}{6},0, \frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\cdots.$$
This is a pseudo-Cauchy sequence, and every real number between $0$ and $1$ is the limit of a subsequence of our sequence.

Comment: Is there a precise way to quantify the rule of this sequence

Comment: You mean find an explicit formula? Yes, it can be done, but is unenlightening.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Do you just have an arsenal of "useful" sequences which you call upon, or did you think of this one at the top of your head. I wonder because I am unsure if I should have been able to intuitively derive such a sequence, or if I was unprepared in not building my arsenal.
I ask this as a student studying undergraduate real analysis 1, sitting an exam in 7 weeks.

Comment: This one I made up quite a while ago. Of course many thousands have made up something similar, but I do not remember reading it. May be just poor memory. Yes, one does acquire a stock of examples that perhaps with modification are useful in a new setting. The standard example for your question is the partial sums of the harmonic series. In my example above, convergence fails much more spectacularly. For explicit formula, it is a bit more convenient to work with numbers of the form $\frac{k}{2^n}$, where $n$ ranges over the positive integers, and $k$ ranges from $0$ to $2^{n}-1$.

Comment: How would we go about proving this sequence is psuedo cauchy by using the definition?

Answer (score 6):

Sequence $$a_n = \sqrt n$$ is pseudo-Cauchy but divergent. It is monotonic, strictly increasing. but not bounded, and divergent.

Let it through the sine function and we get another pseudo-Cauchy sequence $$b_n = \sin(\sqrt n),$$ which is bounded (oscillating between $-1$ and $1$) but not convergent, either.

Answer (score 5):

For the record it doesn't even work if you ask $a_n$ to be bounded. Take $a_n = \sin(\sum_1^n 1/k)$. Since $\sum_1^n 1/k → ∞ $ and also the difference $\left|\sum_1^{n+1} 1/k - \sum_1^n 1/k\right| = \frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$, $a_n$ oscillates between 1 and -1 forever. But as $\sin$ is Lipschitz,
$$|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| \leq \left|\sum_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_1^n \frac{1}{k} \right| = \frac{1}{n+1} → 0$$

Comment: Your conclusion is correct but incomplete. Define $b_n = \sin(\sum_1^n \pi)$. Then $\sum_1^n \pi \to \infty$, but $b_n$ does not oscillate between $1$ and $-1$ forever.

Comment: Thank you, I have added to the argument.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinKhor this is a very interesting example. I feel it will be useful in future :)

Comment: You're welcome :)