# Finding a sequence a with $\lim_{ n\to ∞} (a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$ a:divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Question is in the title. I would appreciate any help with this as I am a bit clueless.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ is divergent?  Or rather, more accurately written, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ is divergent

Comment: Yes, the series is divergent but the sequence isn't, or is it?

Comment: And a series is a sequence of partial sums.  S.C.B. already spelled out what I was trying to get at with my hints below

Comment: Related: [Pseudo-Cauchy sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1237655)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $a_{n}=H_{n}$ where $H_{n}$ denotes the $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), $$\lim_{n \to \infty} H_{n+1}-H_{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1}=0$$

However, the [Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) is divergent.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't quite understand as I have to find a sequence which has to be divergent but in your case it's konvergent isn't it?

Comment: $a_{n}=H_{n}$, and as posted in the link, $H_{n}$ is divergent so $a_{n}$ is divergent.

Comment: @user406473 you want a sequence (in this case $H_n$) where the sequence itself is divergent, but the related sequence of differences (in this case $H_{n+1}-H_n$) has limit equal to zero

Comment: @user406473 Do you understand?

Comment: but if I write my sequence now as Hn = 1/n, its konvergent. Sorry I guess I am really dumb right now lol.

Comment: @user406473 $H_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} \neq \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: but that's a series..

Comment: And as per my comment above, all that a series is is a sequence of partial sums

Comment: @user406473 No, a series can be a sequence. For example, let $a_{n}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}i$. Then $a_{1}=1, a_{2}=3, a_{3}=6 \dots$ that is a sequence

Comment: is every series a sequence?

Comment: I'll say it a third time, a series is a sequence of partial sums.  This is true for every series, yes, every series is a sequence of partial sums, i said it a fourth time.

Comment: @user406473 Every series is a sequence as long as it has some corresponding natural number to it. Every number can be a sequence as well.

Comment: alright thanks to both of you I think I understand it now :)

Answer (score 3):

Take $a_n=\ln n$. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)\Big]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\frac{n+1}{n}=\ln\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}\right]=\ln 1=0$$